# Symfony2 functions for use in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.4

Is there any special way a function (like converting a given string to an array) should be declared in Symfony2? Please keep in mind that the function is only meant to be used in *one class*, so Dependency Injection does not do the job. What I personally like is to not put it directly in the controller as a extra function, but put it into a class, so it fits the separation of concerns.

### Redacted example

I would have something like this:

```
<?php
// ...
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query;

    // Do something with this data
    $data['somedata']['hello'] = $query->get('a');
    $data['someohterdata']['goodbye'] = $query->get('b');
    $data['c'] = $query->get('c');

    $response = new JsonResponse();

    $response->setData($data);
    return $response;
}
```

And what I'm trying to accomplish is something like this

```
<?php

public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query;

    // Access something outside this class
    $outsideClass = ...;
    $data = $outsideClass->createDataFromQuery($query);

    $response = new JsonResponse();

    $response->setData($data);
}
```

Not sure what is best practice, so asking it here.

Comment: Static method call WhateverModel::convertStringToArray( $string ) ? I would probably still inject the object...

Comment: How do you suggest I inject it? I'm pretty new to the PSR-0 autoloading thing.

Comment: It probably depends on what you need to do, and where this functionality logically would sit. If you could post a more specific example, I could put my 2 cents in :)

Comment: Just edited my question and added an example, hope you get the idea :)

Comment: Sounds like something controller-specific, how about a protected helper method in the controller? If it is not controller-specific, you might want to think about injecting a service in your controller.

Comment: Aha, but doesn't that ignore how controllers should be? 'skinny controllers' is what I heard is important.

Comment: I guess you are right, and the controller would not be the most elegant with a protected method. However, injecting a service to parse the input, or letting the model do a specific job like this, seems even worse to me. If you find the right way to do this, please update your post that I would be interested to hear about it :)

Comment: I now have 2 solutions, one that is not reusable: putting the function in the controller as an protected method; and 2: injecting it as an service. Neither one is perfect, and it might even be better just to  `use ..\Utils\RequestDataHandler as DataHandler;` and call it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple:

```
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->query;

    // Access something outside this class
    $data = $query;

    $response = new JsonResponse();

    $response->setData($data);
}
```

It's a normally, if you want to use dynamic response

Comment: Sorry, this was not what I was looking for. The variables from the query are aliased in the function, and I failed to show that in the demo. The function changes things, and then returns them.